# The use of LS estimation with Vector OFDM

Tags: digital-communications, estimation, ofdm, equalization

I work in Vector OFDM, but I had an issue in channel estimation in that scheme. For example, I try to use LS channel estimation but I can't get the performance back. However, in conventional OFDM, I can use that estimation straightforward.

First, let me present the difference of VOFDM compared with OFDM, the V-OFDM scheme is presented as below figure:

[image]

As you see, the only difference that in V-OFDM divides the data bock into vectors and then process them by vectors.

My question is how to use channel estimation based on pilot insertion in this case ?? any channel estimator such as for example LS. I tried different inserting the pilots in similar way of that in OFDM, but I can't get the performance back !!

Thank you

Comment: How do you insert the pilot. Suppose there is a frequency grid of 72 sub carriers allocated, now how do you place the pilots?

Comment: That's what I'm asking about ..   I tried inserting then, for example, 1:4:end as vector. It means when reshaping the transmitted signal, S, I insert the column vectors 1:4:end as pilots, and then use LS as receiver,  but I don't get the performance back.

Comment: In conventional 3gpp LTE protocol, a pilot symbol is available at every 6th sub carrier (at least, for one antenna port transmission), the other subcarriers are used for data symbol then at the received these pilots are filtered and interpolated in freuency to get an estimate of channel for all of the frequency grid, let's say in this example all of the 72 sub carriers. Then using these estimates the data is  demodulated for each of the subcarriers, you could use ML or anything. In you case once you map the vectors on a frequency grid for that symbol you could find suitable placement of pilots

Comment: Let's say you have 4x1 vectors, you could make every 4th subcarrier s pilot and other three are data, then interpolate as explained above and demodulate data subcarriers based on the estimates of channel at each subcarrier.

Comment: @Dspguysam Thank you for your feedback ... Yep, I totally agree with you, but  the problem that doesn't work !!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you have a plot or you could explain what parameters degrade?

Comment: @Dspguysam As I described above .. the V-OFDM, we take the iFFT horizontally, and then we reshape the data vertically ... that  will be different compared with OFDM. So, when using estimated the channel based on 1:4:end and then equalizing in the received side, I can't get the data back. for example the BER can't be found !   here is the example code I have made for that : https://www.mediafire.com/file/y5ysa4g7am93o9k/VOFDM_mine.m/file

Comment: By the way least squares would not be a good estimator in case the noise power modelled is high relative to signal power. It's as good as zero forcing I would say (which is known to boost noise) in such scenarios, it's better to use LMMSE in this case

Comment: @Dspguysam I tried using MMSE and LMMSE .. but That's not working compared with OFDM .. I attached the code as reference

Comment: Ok, let's try the simple case, if you just transmit 4 subcarriers with 1 pilot, does the simulation yield proper results?

Comment: In V-OFDM, vector pilots should be transmitted for channel estimation. In conventional OFDM, pilot symbols are transmitted for channel estimation.

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad Could you please explain what you mean and how I can do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for late reply .. I was little bit busy.

you have mistakes in your code. Although mythology is right, you have mistakes in some parameters.

Check this paper "**Low-Complexity Equalization of Orthogonal Signal-Division Multiplexing in Double-Selective Channels**" Then,  Modify your code following part II in that paper. It's with details there, if you got any issue, you'd let me know. 
Regarding the channel estimation, you follow the same way of conventional OFDM scheme except for V-OFDM you use Vectors pilots instead of symbol pilots.  I means in that mentioned paper, you will have vector of size $M$ used as pilots.

Good luck

Comment: The channel estimation still doesn't work !!

Comment: Again, following that paper I mentioned above, and assuming that you built the parameters in Eq. (7) correctly. let's have $U = F^M ∧^M$. So to estimate the channel of vector $x_l$ based on received vector $y_l$,  you should follow this equation $h_l = inv(diag(Ux_l))*Uy_l$ . Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much ... I got it after suffering for almost couple weeks